# SAML SSO Unsure how a user gets to the protected SP page for IDP initiated SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, idp

I currently maintain an in-house SAML IDP written utilising LightSaml. This has served the company well for the last 2 years working with SP initiated SSO. I have recently been tasked with implementing IDP initiated SSO and I'm not able to work out how the user is automatically redirected to the desired protected page once they're authenticated.

In SP initiated SSO, the user starts at the page they want, therefore the SP knows where they want to end up after being authenticated. So in this case, the SP handles the final redirection.

In IDP initiated SSO, the SP doesn't actually know what protected page the user wants, so could someone explain what happens after the IDP sends the auth response to the SP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IdP-initiated SSO, along with the SAML response, the IdP can send relay state. This relay state is the URL the SP should redirect to once SSO completes. If no relay state is sent, the SP will most likely redirect to some default page.

A typical scenario is that the IdP has a portal page with one or more links representing different pages at the SP. If the user clicks link #1, the IdP initiates SSO to the SP and sets the relay state to the page #1 URL. If the user clicks link #2, the IdP initiates SSO to the SP and sets the relay state to the page #2 URL.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will make my work quite simple.

Comment: As a small comment to this. The relay state is often used to send the URL for the page that the user should be send to after auth. It not always the case tough and can contain any thing to represent the state of the user at the SP. From the SAML view this can be any value and will simply be echoed back together with the authenticated user.

Comment: What you've said applies to SP-initiated SSO only. The question relates to IdP-initiated SSO where the relay state has a completely different purpose as described in my answer.